# A local object disappeared from $TMP. How to find it?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, s4hana

There was a local report in the `$TMP` that is "disappeared" somehow. I did not delete it, but can't see it in `SE80` anymore.

What could be the reason?
Somebody else has deleted it. The system has been resetted somehow to an older backup state. Are any other reasons possible?

Is there a possibility to see in the traces what has happened or are there any other (better) tracking possibilities?
Unfortunately I don't know what was the exact name of the disappeared report, but I know the beginning of its name (like Z_ABCD_...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot restore or track local objects if they were deleted. There could  be any reason from that you have mentioned. Better ask collegues / basic team if they made some changes.

Try to look up the table **TADIR** (Directory of Repository Objects) to check which local development objects exist. Use `SE16` / `SE16N` transaction with condition `DEVCLASS` = `$TMP`, additionally `AUTHOR` to include only objects from specific user, `OBJ_NAME` = `Z_ABCD*` to restrict the program name.

You can also check the table **REPOSRC** (Report Source Code), where reports source code in RAWSTRING (`DATA` field) is stored. Filter on `PROGNAME`, `CNAM` (username) to check if the source sode is available on the system (there are also several views avaiable for this table, `TRDIR`, `D010SINF`).

If the program were assigned to a package / transport and deleted, than you could find it in `TADIR` with a deletion flag `DELFLAG` = `X`, and also in the table `E071` with `OBJFUNC` = `D` in case of a transport assignment. Local objects just get deleted from the repository tables.

Comment: yes, the idea with TADIR was a good one :)